# Why does gnome system monitor take a gig of memory?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I'm using the gnome system monitor applet/application to watch what goes on in my ubuntu machine, and when I sort by memory size, the program itself takes up 1.3 gig, 870meg resident.
It's a stupid little monitoring program. Is there any way to get it to waste less memory?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Does the `free` command report similar values to what gnome-system-monitor reports?

There was a [**bug**](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=489555) in older builds of gnome-system-monitor that would cause it to report incorrect memory usage amounts. Linux also uses more memory when available to increase overall system performance, similar to that of Windows 7. Having a lot of memory in use is not necessarily a bad thing as [**memory access times are much faster than disk access times**](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.731942.7), so the more your OS can hold in memory the better. Unused RAM is wasted RAM.

Comment: Free reports the same, I'm just thinking that the program itself is just a crazy hog for what it does. I've gotten to the point where I think swap is almost completely useless, I never use swap, everything's in memory all the time, which is why it concerns me that this silly tool it taking up an entire gig of memory.